# Filtering Gmail for emails that include a plus sign

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I know you can filter emails in Gmail by utilizing plus signs (e.g., bob+something@gmail.com).  But is there a way to filter for the opposite - that is, include emails in gmail **only** where a plus sign is included (and regardless of what it is)?  E.g., only show `bob+xx@gmail.com` or `bob+zz@gmail.com`, but not `bob@gmail.com`?

Comment: I assume you're referring to gmail's filter mechanism?

Comment: If you mean you want to filter f.e. the e-mail address `foo+bar@gmail.com` then the answer is that e-mail addresses cannot contain + signs. If you didn't meant this, your question is formulated quite weirdly...

Comment: @stevenroose: You certainly _can_ use plus signs in email addresses. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-can-i-filter-incoming-email-based-on-plus-addressing-in-gmail

Comment: Alas, there is no wildcard search in Gmail. I had hoped that something like `to:bob+*@gmail.com` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @AlEverett Wow, didn't know that. I saw it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: I believe google is built around searching words, rather than fractions of words. There is a piece here: http://google.about.com/od/googlepowersearches/qt/wildcardqt.htm that covers use of wildcards but only for word replacement, I suspect that search methodology extends to email search too. It does appear to separate the name and domain portions of the address into 2 words however.

Comment: I agree with @DannyParker. I tried a simple test for `to:(bob gmail.com -bob@gmail.com)` that intuitively would have found the cases with the + (and maybe other stuff). In my tests, it only found the other stuff. For example, it found some old emails that were sent to a mailing list address that had `To:users-sc.1234567.abcdefg-bob=gmail.com@spamassassin.apache.org`. That implies to me that Gmail could find the individual words inside the To: addresses, but when there's a + between them, it's somehow making them atoms (binding them). I have lots of emails with "+" in the To:, by the way.

Comment: Also, searching for `To:+` or `To:"+"` finds all mail, implying the + character means nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a filter for each of these `foo+xxx@` addresses. Example:

Create a filter with on the `To:` field for `foo+bar@domain.com` OR `foo+xxx@domain.com`

Use the filter to apply a label and then you can just view emails under this label.

It's not very scalable if you have a lot of these types of address to filter on, but it will work if there are only a handful, and it will prevent you from having to run a script.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for all emails addressed to bob@gmail.com (which would not return bob+anything@gmail.com), apply a label to them, and then filter for all email without that label.

This will also pick up emails that you receive at addresses other than bob, but if there are a limited number of such addresses you could also search for them and apply the same label.

Comment: This isn't going to cover things like mailing lists where the recipient's email address doesn't appear in the To: header at all.

Comment: @octern "search for all emails addressed to bob@gmail.com (which would not return bob+anything@gmail.com)": **not true**.  I am guessing you didn't test it.  I just tested this with (the equivalent of) "*to:me*", "*to:myaddressstart@gmail.com*", and even "*deliveredto:myaddressstart@gmail.com*", and they all returned all converstations with e-mails to me, with and without + addresses.

Comment: I seem to recall using this method in the past. It might have changed since then. Either way, this was never a great solution and now it's a nonfunctional one.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `-`

It is used to exclude terms from your search.

Example: `nerd -dinner`

Meaning: Messages that contain the word "nerd" but do not contain the word "dinner".

Try it. You can read better on [Google Support](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190).

Comment: -1 as this doesn't work for addresses, which is what the original poster asked.