# Labeling everything that is auto-forwarded from a (non-Gmail) account

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I've got several email accounts, but I always set them up to be auto forwarded to the main one, so I always check just one inbox. This is awesome, but sometimes I need labels to organize and categorize work, promos, academic, etc...

Lets suppose main account is `julian@gmail.com`, academic is `julian@university.edu`, and work is `julian@company.com`, What I have now is academic and company forwarding everything automatically to Gmail, and it's working, and some labels are working as well, but there are some groups such as `math@university.edu` that is a list to all of the students in that class, or `project@company.com` that has same behavior.

I set up a label called "academic" to everything in Gmail that matches `To:julian@university.edu`, and in this scenario is working:

```
From: martin@university.edu
To: julian@university.edu
(julian@university.edu forwards everything to julian@gmail.com)
So in inbox, I see "To: julian@university.edu", and that conversation gets the label!
```

But, let's suppose this scenario:

```
From: martin@university.edu
To: math@university.edu
(It's forwarded auto to all students, so julian@university.edu receives it)
(julian@university.edu forwards everything to julian@gmail.com)
So in inbox, I see "To: math@university.edu", and that conversation does not get the label!
```

I don't want to modify the label so it consider julian@university.edu AND math@university.edu, it's just not practical, there are like 15 groups among university, familiar and work, so filters would be a bit confuse.

Is there a way that Gmail detects that email is being forwarded FROM academic, without taking into account the TO and FROM fields, so it puts the correct label on it?

The `deliveredto` field was quite useful for admin by google accounts, but that field seems to stop working when secondary accounts are not Google, such as Gmail or a simple cpanel email account. How do I get same effect with different accounts?

Comment: I don't think your change *really* makes it into a different question, but I'm willing to reopen it for the time being.  It may get reclosed by the community.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "julian+whatever@gmail.com" syntax?

IIRC, from your university.edu account you can forward everything to **julian+univ@gmail.com** and it will be delivered to **julian@gmail.com**.

You can then label every mail received which has a to ***"TO Field" : julian+univ@gmail.com***

*I use a lot this syntax, the major downside is when some people/forms do not know the syntax and insist that the email address you just entered is invalid.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't use that syntax, but IDK if I'm understanding wrong, or if just not working. What I did: from julian@company.com I set up to forward everything to julian+work@gmail.com, and it's working, I made a few tests sending emails to julian@company.com and I see it in gmail inbox. but when I search `to:julian+work@gmail.com` at gmail inbox, nothing comes up!

Comment: I found this question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-can-i-filter-incoming-email-based-on-plus-addressing-in-gmail which might help you. I just searched my gmail inbox for these kind of mails and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a header `X-Forwarded-For:` that contains where the email is forwarding from. Maybe you can make use of that.

If that fails/being-impossible, why don't your simplify your "academic" label to match `To:@university.edu`, instead of the specific `To:julian@university.edu` one. That should be a pretty accurate filter that would be correct 99.99% of the times.