# I use gmail email suffixes as mentioned in this link, but how to ensure 'reply-to' always retains the 'from' address

Tags: gmail

I have several gmail addresses with which I use the [plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-can-i-filter-incoming-email-based-on-plus-addressing-in-gmail) to point out spammers; but when responding to emails from sites where I had registered with a '+', when I reply, it always goes bask to default gmail address (which is something totally different) and confuses the heck out of them.

How do I prevent this ? Had asked this in google forums which led nowhere, wondering if the folks here know a 'hack' for this!

Pretty sad that google would not address this even after more than a decade.